# Is there a way to combine two tokens from a list of tokens?

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I was wondering if we can add the tokens if there is specific token after the token. For example:

```
This is a test token and it is a test to see if it works.
```

In the sentence above let's say we get token as:

```
token ='This','is', 'a','test','token','and','it','is','a','test','to',see'....
```

What I want to do is if there is a token called `token`, I want `test token` to be single token.

I have looked around and tried everything but I couldn't fix it.

Comment: Any reason for [regex]?

Comment: @ vaultah, I was trying to learn regex as a tokenizer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think you mean this,.

```
>>> import re
>>> s = "This is a test token and it is a test to see if it works."
>>> re.findall(r'\btest token\b|\S+', s)
['This', 'is', 'a', 'test token', 'and', 'it', 'is', 'a', 'test', 'to', 'see', 'if', 'it', 'works.']
```

Comment: or `re.findall(r'(?<!\S)test token(?!\S)|\S+', s)`

Comment: This regex works if we know there is word test infront of every token but we don't know if there is word test infront right.

Comment: @Sam but is this the appropriate approach, you want the word immediately preceding the target to be part of the same token?

Comment: In this case, you might try the same approach with regex `r'\b(\w+ token|\w+)\b'`

Comment: I think whether to use `\w` or `\S` depends on whether OP wants to strip or include punctuation, which is not clear from the question, but I would strip it.

Comment: Thank you AvinashRaj and @tobias_k for your help