# joining two strings in a list of strings based, if two specific string occur after one another

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I'm trying to combine two strings in a list, where the combination of the terms have a different meaning compared to when they are tokenized individually.

An example of this would be:

```
['I', 'want','to','join','a','football','team','in','2022']
```

The goal is to join the strings `'football'` and `'team'`, with a `_` if the two terms occur after one another, resulting in this string `football_team`.

The final list would looks like this:

```
['I', 'want','to','join','a','football_team','in','2022']
```

Any help is appreciated as I only get to the point where I can join the whole list.

EDIT:

I have been trying to join terms using this:
[Is there a way to combine two tokens from a list of tokens?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33041182/is-there-a-way-to-combine-two-tokens-from-a-list-of-tokens/33041334)

Also I have tried this, but it joins every element in the list:
[How to concatenate items in a list to a single string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12453580/how-to-concatenate-items-in-a-list-to-a-single-string)

EDIT 2:

In answer to a question in the comments, "How would one understand which words would hold some meaning?"

I have a pre-defined list of string combinations that need to be merged.

Comment: How would one understand which words would hold some meaning?

Comment: *"I'm trying to"*: can you include what you have been trying, so we see where you are stuck?

Comment: You could keep track of the words that can be merged with a dictionary of type Dict[str, Set[str]]. In your for loop you could look at the next word and if it's in the Set part of your dictionary you could merge those two words.

Comment: But be aware if you use a for loop, it can cause a little error if you remove one of the words after merging. I would use a while loop.

Comment: I think you want to search for some specific words from a list of strings and then join them in a single string, so you can use any one of the ML libraries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
" ".join(['I', 'want','to','join','a','football','team','in','2022']).replace("football team","football_team").split(" ")
```

Answer (score 1):

By this way you can define an arbitrary set of pairs.

```
pairs = {"football" : "team"}

a_list = ['I', 'want','to','join','a','football','team','in','2022']
list_copy = a_list.copy()

for one, another in zip(list_copy.copy()[:-1], list_copy.copy()[1:]):
    if one in pairs and another == pairs[one]:
        i = a_list.index(one)
        del a_list[i:i+2]
        a_list.insert(i, one + "_" + another)
```